# how to make 11 button in matrix

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit

I want to make 11 buttons specified below order with 2 for loops, it is a matrix but for 11 buttons.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 2; i++) {

  for (int k = 1; k <= 6; k++) {

   j++;

   NSString *key = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Color%d",j];

   UIColor *color = [dict objectForKey:key];

   ColorBtn *colorBtn  = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
   colorBtn.frame = CGRectMake(4+(startPointX*k), 320+(startPointY*i), 38, 37);
   colorBtn.backgroundColor = color;
   colorBtn.tag = j;
   [colorBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
   [colorBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(SetUIColor:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
   [self.view addSubview:colorBtn];
  }
 }

[][][][][][]
[][][][][]
```

Comment: -1: What language? You've 4 completely different language tags on this question.

Comment: This loop runs 12 (6 * 2) times.

Comment: @Binary: The code snippet looks like objc. I have retagged the question a bit.

Comment: so what's your question again?

Comment: @JustSid:  There's a question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add a few lines to your inner `for` loop towards the top:

```
...
j++;

// Add these lines
if (i == 2 && k == 6) {
  continue;
}
// Add these lines

NSString *key = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Color%d",j];
...
```

This will ensure that the final column in the second row is skipped.

---

Another alternative is to check the value of `j` - this would allow you to change the dimensions of your matrix while still ensuring only 11 entries are created in total:

```
...
j++;

// Add these lines
// I'm assuming that j is 1-based, not 0-based
if (j > 11) {
  break;
}
// Add these lines

NSString *key = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Color%d",j];
...
```

Answer (score 0):

for (int i = 1; i <= 2; i++) {

for (int k = 1; k <= 6; k++) {

j++;
       if(j<12)
          {
              //Your code for creating buttons.

```
       }
```

}
 }

for j=0(at starting).